# check delivery table doesnt exists

Tags: magento-1.9

I have used extension for Check availability by zip/postal code from magento connect. By default it has to create checkdelivery table but its not creating,,, so i'm getting following error as in snapshot. i have reinstalled many times. So please guide me what steps have to done. and also show steps how to import and export files. Give me proper instructions.
[image: snapshot of admin page]
[image]

Comment: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/ You need to rerun the install script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing database tables for this extension you are using.
Check database and try to install extension manually in place of Magento connect.Hope it will work.

Comment: i have tried manually nw table is created but with empty column of zipcode. i have also tried by updating database but again its not checking in magento frontend.

Comment: Try to install this module in fresh Magento setup maybe your core files will be edited.

Comment: i want information of how to import or why to export files